# Strip json to array from Aggreation pipeline MongoDB

Tags: aggregation-framework

I am performing an aggregation in order to have an array for suggestions of tags, on the client side I'm using a typeahead like plug in.

the main idea would be to send directly the sorted array from the server side, so the browser has not to do any work on "stripping" the json.

So far I got this

```
    suggestion.aggregate([
        {$match  : {}},
        {$sort : { 'pop' : -1 } },
        {$limit:10000},
        {$project : { _id: 0,tag : 1 } }
    ],  
    function (err,tags) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (req.xhr) {
        res.send(tags);
        tags=[];
        return;
      }
      res.send(tags); 
      tags=[];
    }
  );
```

Which send a Json like this:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "news"
  },
  {
    "tag": "tech"
  },
  {
    "tag": "sports"
  },
  ....
]
```

And I would like to send from the server something like this (avoiding map reduce or forEach function):

```
 [
    "news",
    "tech",
    "sports",
    ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a group operator at the end of the pipeline to achieve this:

```
suggestion.aggregate([
        {$match  : {}},
        {$sort : { 'pop' : -1 } },
        {$limit:10000},
        {$project : { _id: 0,tag : 1 } },
        {$group:{"_id":null,"tagArray":{$push:"$tag"}}}
    ])
```